# CookieTheftException with PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using the PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices (Spring Security 2.04) in [Grails](http://grails.org) App in conjunction with the OpenIDAuthenticationProcessingFilter. The configuration is as follows (This is [Grails's](http://grails.org) DSL equivalent to Spring resource.xml but it should be quite easy to adapt):

```
customTokenRepository(JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl)
{
  dataSource = ref('dataSource')
}

rememberMeServices(PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices) {
    userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
    key = securityConf.rememberMeKey
    cookieName = securityConf.cookieName
    alwaysRemember = securityConf.alwaysRemember
    tokenValiditySeconds = securityConf.tokenValiditySeconds
    parameter = securityConf.parameter
    tokenRepository = customTokenRepository
}

openIDAuthProvider(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.openid.GrailsOpenIdAuthenticationProvider) {
    userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
}

openIDStore(org.openid4java.consumer.InMemoryConsumerAssociationStore)

openIDNonceVerifier(org.openid4java.consumer.InMemoryNonceVerifier, securityConf.openIdNonceMaxSeconds) // 300 seconds

openIDConsumerManager(org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager) {
    nonceVerifier = openIDNonceVerifier
}

openIDConsumer(org.springframework.security.ui.openid.consumers.OpenID4JavaConsumer, openIDConsumerManager)

openIDAuthenticationProcessingFilter(org.springframework.security.ui.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationProcessingFilter) {
    authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
    authenticationFailureUrl = securityConf.authenticationFailureUrl //'/login/authfail?login_error=1' // /spring_security_login?login_error
    defaultTargetUrl = securityConf.defaultTargetUrl // '/'
    filterProcessesUrl = '/j_spring_openid_security_check' // not configurable
    rememberMeServices = ref('rememberMeServices')
    consumer = openIDConsumer
    targetUrlResolver = customTargetUrlResolver
}
```

After a user has authenticated everything is fine until the cookie issued to him  is used for the first time for example after a container restart (see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/xref/org/springframework/security/ui/rememberme/PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.html#77)).

The very first request using the cookie seems to be always fine but after the cookie has been updated with a new date and most importantly a new token, subsequent requests will crash in [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/xref/org/springframework/security/ui/rememberme/PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.html#87). As if the browser would still request resources using the old version of the cookie containing the old token. I'm totally baffled why this happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: For clarification - You are getting this error after you restart your servlet container?  Is that something you do often, and why?

Comment: I get it after a container restart yes. But my research has shown that it can basically happen anytime a user's has expired and Spring Security attempts to auto-login the user using the cookie issued earlier.

Comment: Can you simply catch the Exception and send the user back to the login URI?

Comment: Sure I can but that defeats the purpose of having a cookie to save the user from logging in all the time isn't it? :)

Comment: Not really - cookies expire, and it sounds like your issue is that when the cookie expires you get this exception.  So just have them log back in.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree with you Gandalf. The problem is it happens after a couple minutes regardless of the cookie lifetime.